# rand() doesn't work even with srand( time(NULL) )

Tags: c++, random, srand

So I'm trying to generate random integers inside functions, but it returns the same numbers. `NUM_SOURCES == 5` and for all 5 repetitions it gives the same number despite `srand(time(0))` being called. I tried the same without `std::`, but the result did not change.

Any suggestions?

```
std::srand(time(0)); //setting seed
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SOURCES; i++)
                         {
                             if (sourceDeq->at(i)->getCurrentBid() == NULL) // If the source is empty, generate a new order
                             {
                                 sourceDeq->at(i)->setCurrentBid(sourceDeq->at(i)->generateBid(systemTime));
                             }
                         }
    ...
    Bid* Source::generateBid(int sysTime)
    {
        bidAmount = bidAmount + 1;
        return new Bid(bidAmount, generateTimeCreation(sysTime), 0, 0, 0, getNumber());
    }
    ...

    int Source::generateTimeCreation(int sysTime)
    {
        srand(0);
        if (sLaw == UNIFORM)
            return (sysTime + std::rand() % 10);
        if (sLaw == EXPONENTIAL)
            return(sysTime + round((1 - exp(-(std::rand() % 100))) * 10));
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your code so it doesn't run off the right side of the window?

Comment: You're calling `srand` too often. One time is enough.

Comment: PRNGs aren't actually random. They start with a seed and generate a sequence of numbers with a certain period. You usually provide the seed *once* and then generate random numbers, as the state of the PRNG will change on its own. By seeding it over and over with the same number (your code probably runs in one millisecond), you will always get the same sequence of random numbers.

Comment: It appears that you _might_ call srand() outside the scope of the function, could you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`srand(0);` initializes the random number generator *again*, so it will have the same results, every time... Don't do it.

The whole point of calling with `time(NULL)` is to provide a *random* seed.

Comment: Holy lulz, how dumb am I. Thx, man! That's just what happens when you spend hours in front of monitor.